# Securing Always Encrypted SQL Server from "sa"

Tags: sql-server, ssms, always-encrypted

I'm currently studying SQL Server Always Encrypted feature. How can I disable column decryption to "sa" if all they have to do is add `Column Encryption Setting=enabled` in the login's additional login parameters in SQL Server Management Studio?

I read articles in Google. They only said we can secure data from admins but no example how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column encryption key (CEK) is used to encrypt the data and is stored in the database. The CEK is secured using  a column master key (CMK).

The CMK is stored outside of SQL Server. Metadata about the key is stored within SQL Server.

If you restrict access to the CMK your database administrators / system administrators (sa) will not have the ability to decrypt.

Comment: hi Jon, can you point me to a tutorial website about this? i tried every tutorial in youtube and google but they stopped in the Column Encryption Setting=enabled part

Comment: I would start with the following. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-and-store-column-master-keys-always-encrypted

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon,its now working, I used local user certificates.

Answer (score -3):

You can't simply because the key all stored in the catalog, and the catalog is unrestricted to `sa`.

I didn't write the query, I just googled for `sys.column_encryption_key_values` (which I knew stored the sym encryption keys), and [found someone else who did the work.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/Raul+Garcia+-+MS)

```
SELECT cek.name, cmk.key_path, cekv.encrypted_value, cekv.encryption_algorithm_name
FROM sys.column_encryption_key_values cekv, sys.column_encryption_keys cek, sys.column_master_key_definitions cmk
WHERE cek.column_encryption_key_id = cekv.column_encryption_key_id
   AND cmk.column_master_key_definition_id = cekv.column_master_key_definition_id;
```

All bets are off with symmetric encryption if someone gets root.

Comment: so that means, all of my encrypted confidential data can be decrypted by any admin even if they supposedly have no access to view it?

Comment: "supposedly have no access to view it"  "SA" is "System Admin" if you have that user enabled (Mixed Auth) then you're in for a world of pain if that user is compromised. That's how the DB works.

Comment: ok thanks...last question..is there a way to block `Column Encryption Setting=enabled` on non admin user...i tried to create one and adding this to parameter also decrypt the data

Comment: The CMK is stored outside of SQL Server, so the person would need to have the SA login, sql auth enabled, **AND** and copy of the certificate or access to a HSM with credentials for said HSM in order to get this to work with Always Encrypted. Definitely not trivial as you make it out to seem. @user3204806